# Set default state value in ngrx reducer

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

In store I have several array, string etc.

```
export const INITIAL_TEST_STORE: TestState = {
    one: null,
    two: null,
    three: false,
    four: {},
};
```

And above, you can see initial state values - all are working properly.

But when I dispatched clear action (and setting initial state):

```
on(clearState, state => ({
    ...INITIAL_TEST_STORE
})),
```

the `four` node has still old value, not empty {}

If I dispatch below action:

```
on(clearState, state => ({
    ...INITIAL_TEST_STORE,
    four: {}
})),
```

Everything is clear properly. And I am wondering why? The problem is with immutable? But... it is that same...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spread operator does the Shallow copy of the object, `four` is the nested level object and spread operator will not reset it.

```
on(clearState, state => ({
    ...INITIAL_TEST_STORE
    four: { ...INITIAL_TEST_STORE.four }
})),
```

snippet about should reset the state.

Comment: It will reset it? Try `{... {four: {a:1}}, ...{four: {}}}` this will result in `{four:{}}`

Comment: Shallow copy was the original issue, i highlighted that and show the approach where if there are more nested objects on object `four` how it can be reset.

Answer (score 0):

Is `INITIAL_TEST_STORE` updated somewhere else in the codebase?
You can make sure of it if you debug the reducer.

fyi, you can also just return `INITIAL_TEST_STORE` without the spread operator, but that won't change the outcome.

Comment: Nope. Only during initalization the store and after dispatching clearState action. Ach, without spread operator... but why it is not working with spread? Update all keys/values without the Object four one.

Comment: I have no idea, do you have a reproduction?